# Rigorous proof of quantum electrodynamics renormalization

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

In most physics books they give  proofs of renormalization of quantum electrodynamics that are not  mathematically rigorous.

Is there any book or article that give a formal proof of quantum electrodynamics renormalization in the mathematical sense?

Comment: What does it mean to give a "mathematically rigorous proof" of a physical phenomena?

Comment: If quantum electrodynamics is renormalizable  there  should a theoretical proof of it.   what i meant to say is ,assuming that qft is a correct framework  than from it there should be a proof  in the mathematical sense

Comment: I think you mean "In most physics books they give proofs of renormalization of quantum electrodynamics that is **not** mathematically rigorous"

Comment: yes you are right,  my mistake

Comment: That's because they are busy trying to renormalize quantum gravity...

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.4700.pdf

They claim that references 3 & 4 give more advanced literature on the topic.

Comment: We  do not have any rigorously defined interacting QFT in 3+1 dimensions. There are some in 1+1 and 2+1. See [A Perspective on Constructive Quantum Field Theory, Stephen J. Summers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3991).

Comment: so what people mean when they say that qed is renormanizable?

Comment: You can Google many explanations. Mathematical Physicist John Baez gives an [explanation](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/renormalization.html) without equations or Feynman diagrams. (BTW, owners of Questions or Answers are automatically notified of comments but for others you need to put @username (followed by a space)).

Answer (score 4):

The comments above conflate two different kinds of constructions or proofs of renormalizability: perturbative and nonperturbative. Perturbative means that correlation functions are constructed as formal power series in some meaningless symbol which pretends to be a parameter like Planck's constant or the fine structure constant. Nonperturbative means a full construction including a resummation of this power series to give a true function of this parameter with values in say Schwartz distributions. For QED in 4d there is no rigorous nonperturbative construction. In fact it is believed to be impossible (triviality conjecture). However, rigorous perturbative renormalization proofs exist. The most mathematically careful reference I know is: ["QED: A proof of Renormalizability"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3662136635) by Feldman, Hurd and Rosen.